# Drupal 7 query condition NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, select, drupal-7

I'm trying to add a condition for the xml_sitemap table in a query to exclude any "loc" field that starts with node/.  This is what I have below.  I do not think this is working correctly.

```
 $query->condition('loc', 'node/%', 'NOT LIKE');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The xml_sitemap module needs to be hacked directly xml_sitemap.generate.inc for this:  $link_url = url($link['loc'], $link_options + $url_options);